# ¿Por qué serializar un objeto con atributo JsonPropery funciona en modo Debug y no en Release?

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Estoy desarrollando una app con Xamarin para Android

Tengo un objeto con varias propiedades cada una con un atributo **JsonProperty** de esta forma

```
    public class Tarea
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int id{get;set;}

    [JsonProperty]
    public string tarea{get;set;}

}
```

el problema es que cuando hago esto

```
Tarea oTarea = new Tarea();
oTarea.id=1;
oTarea.taera = "mi tarea";
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oTarea);
```

funciona bien en Debug (desde Visual Studio) pero cuando compilo en Release, la cadena json es nula.

he detectado que si sobreescribo la propiedad ToString al objeto,de esta forma

```
public class Tarea
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public int id{get;set;}

        [JsonProperty]
        public string tarea{get;set;}

        public override ToString(){
           return tarea;
        }
    }
```

al serializar si se crea un objeto sólo con la propiedad *tarea* asignada, sin mostrar ninguna propiedad más. 
Finalmente he tenido que serializar otro objeto sin los atributos JsonProperty pero quisiera saber por que funciona en Debug y no en Release.

Comment: Me respondo, era un problema de configuración en la compilación al indicar desde Visual Studio en la opción Android Options->Linker el valor Sdk And User Assemblies y en Advanced selecionar la arquitectura correcta

Answer (score 0):

Puede que sea porque esos decoradores son de una DLL que dentro estén marcados como debug, por lo tanto sólo funcionarían en Debug y no en Release, aunque esto más bein es algo que pasa con los métodos, no con los decoradores.

Puede que tengan puesto en la dll algo parecido a esto:

```
[Conditional("RELEASE")]

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
```